# Why do individual Keys on a notebook become hard to press?

Tags: keyboard, sony-vaio, laptop-repair

From time to time some of the keys on my notebook stop working, unless I press them very hard. Those keys are also harder to press down.

I have had this problem on previous notebooks as well. Strangely some times the problem resolves it self.

Is it correct to assume that something small somehow got under the key and is preventing the key from functioning properly by blocking it physically?

If I press the key very hard, keep it pressed and wiggle it around a little it starts to wrok better.

What is the proper way of solving this problem?

My notebook is: Touch Notebook SONY Vaio Fit multi-flipTM SVF15N1Z2EB

A pic of the Keyboard: [image: Keyboard pic]

Comment: on my new Sony VAIO I had Esc button very hard to press, I pulled it out, and puted back in, and it was working good after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is something under the problem keys, crumbs, for example. Try blowing some compressed air into the gaps around the keys. This worked for me more than once. You can use something like Office Duster.

If that doesn't work, you can also just replace the keyboard, usually they are relatively inexpensive and it's a pretty simple operation.

Take a look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BEcX_0KYIE

(I'm not affiliated with laptopkeyboard.com)

In some keyboards you can safely pop off the keys, in which case you could see what's going on. Not sure about your particular keyboard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0Eow7bdsMY